# GLFW Window poll events lag

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I have a problem handling GLFW poll events. As far as I know, all user input events are handled via callbacks or via constantly checking keyboard / mouse states. The latter is not so efficient an can even result in missing some input (e. g. when button pressed and then released between checking state). What is more, some events like window resizing cannot be handled without callbacks.

So, the problem is that whenever user starts resizing window (presses mouse button but doesn't move mouse), the app seems to freeze. This is, assuming resize callback is enabled and defined validly (even when copied right from [GLFW API](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window_guide.html#window_size)). And the problem **is not** that window doesn't redraw. Redraw on callback can be done with creating and calling own `render()` function in callback function.

The **actual** problem is that even when I handle resize event properly and redraw on callback, there is still some lag. This lag is after mouse press on decorated window border and when mouse is not moving. Here's a demonstration (button click is highlighted green):

[image: Demo GIF]

Sorry for messed up GIF. All callbacks listed in GLFW API are enabled and handled (window-, input-, joystick- and monitor-callbacks) and redraw is called in each one. It seems that I'm missing some of the callbacks or GLFW just works like that.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56614042/15229911) answer, this can't be done without threading:

> That only works when the user moves the mouse while holding - just holding left-click on the resize window part still stalls. **To fix that, you need to render in a separate thread** in addition to this. (**No, you can't do that without threading.** Sorry, this is how GLFW works, no one except them can change it.)

So, the questions are:

1. How can I fix this issue without threading? If I can't, I guess I can emulate resizing with different cursors shapes and resizing zones or smth like that...
2. If this is still impossible to solve in GLFW, do other GLFW alternatives have this issue?
3. Are there any problems with GLFW similar to this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GLFW is not at fault here. It's how the operating system handles certain user input events like mouse down on the decorator resize handles of a window or moving the whole window.

See this answer for a more elaborate detail: [Win32: My Application freezes while the user resizes the window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102074/win32-my-application-freezes-while-the-user-resizes-the-window#answer-3103130)

[GLFW uses the standard Windows PeekMessage -> TranslateMessage/DispatchMessage loop](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/97da62a027794d9ff0f4512268cb9a73a8fb5073/src/win32_window.c#L1963-L1983) which you will find in *any* GUI Windows application. This will get invoked when you call `glfwPollEvents()` and it processes all Window event messages that the OS has accumulated so far for all windows in this process. After all messages so far have been processed, the call to `glfwPollEvents()` will return and will allow your own window/game loop to continue.

What happens is that once the user clicks down the window decoration's resize handles, effectively the call to `glfwPollEvents()` will block within the OS itself in order for the OS / window-manager to intercept the mouse and keyboard messages to do its window resizing/reshaping thing.

I'm afraid that even though Windows will inform the process about the start of a window resize or move action (after which the OS will have control of the window message processing) and [GLFW already handling these events internally](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/97da62a027794d9ff0f4512268cb9a73a8fb5073/src/win32_window.c#L943-L944), right now GLFW will not notify the client application about this. It would be *possible* though for GLFW to provide an appropriate event callback to the application, so that the application can start a timer or thread only for as long as the window resize/move action happens (as is also mentioned in the linked other Stackoverflow answer).

So, the only thing that you can do in order to keep rendering while the user holds onto the resize handles or while the user moves the window around, is to render in a separate thread.

Comment: https://github.com/glfw/glfw/pull/1426